# ORDER BY with UNION clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by, union, where-clause, hsqldb

Everywhere I search I find that having something like the code below is supposed to work.

```
SELECT id, name, age FROM A
UNION
SELECT id, name, age FROM B
ORDER BY name
```

My query is searching every value on the data base between specific dates, and then it is selecting just a few values before that specified date. By itself this query works, but I want to order it by some column, and I'm getting the error:

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator

This is my code:

```
DECLARE @inidate DATE = '20201001', @findate DATE = '20201031'

SELECT bo.id, bo.date, bo.status
FROM BO (nolock)
JOIN BO2 (nolock) ON BO2.bo2stamp = BO.bostamp
WHERE (BO.date BETWEEN @inidate AND @findate)
  AND (BO.tabela1 IN ('INSTALED','CANCELED'))

UNION

SELECT bo.id, bo.date, bo.status
FROM BO (nolock)
JOIN BO2 (nolock) ON BO2.bo2stamp = BO.bostamp
WHERE (BO.date < @inidate)
  AND (BO.tabela1 NOT IN ('INSTALED','CANCELED'))
ORDER BY bo2.u_registration_date
```

I've tried the code shown here, and with it I get an error on `ORDER BY`

> Expected AS, ID, or QUOTED_ID

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    ([my query])
ORDER BY bo2.u_registration_date
```

I've also tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM ([1st query])
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM ([2nd query])
ORDER BY bo2.u_registration_date
```

Comment: The error is telling you the problem; you can't order by `u_registration_date` when it isn't in the `SELECT`. If you *must* have the data in that order but not exposed, then the the `UNION` query in a subquery, with the column, then exclude it in the outer query, but order on it.

Comment: Also do you *really* need those `NOLOCK` hints against every table? You *do* understand what it does, correct? `NOLOCK` isn't a magic "go faster" button, and can easily cause your results to be incorrect. [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, you can't order by u_registration_date since you don't select that column.

Comment: Can you do `UNION ALL` instead? Or do you want/need to eliminate duplicates?

Comment: I've been told to use `nolock` because if I have a great database I might somehow block these tables and can't access it anymore. I trusted the man since my knowledge on SQL is very limited, I've started on it about 2 months ago.

Comment: I don't want any duplicates, but anyway I tried `UNION ALL` and it shows me the same results, so I'll stick to regular `UNION`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to put the `union` in a subquery, and order in the outer query. Also, the subquery needs to return the column that you want to use for sorting.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT bo.id, bo.date, bo.status, bo2.u_registration_date
        FROM BO
        JOIN BO2 ON BO2.bo2stamp = BO.bostamp
        WHERE BO.date BETWEEN @inidate AND @findate AND BO.tabela1 IN ('INSTALED','CANCELED')
    UNION
        SELECT bo.id, bo.date, bo.status, bo2.u_registration_date
        FROM BO
        JOIN BO2 ON BO2.bo2stamp = BO.bostamp
        WHERE BO.date < @inidate AND BO.tabela1 NOT IN ('INSTALED','CANCELED')
) t
ORDER BY u_registration_date
```

Note that using `UNION` here does not make a lot of sense. The two members only differ by their date filter, so functionally your query is equivalent to just:

```
SELECT bo.id, bo.date, bo.status, bo2.u_registration_date
FROM BO
JOIN BO2 ON BO2.bo2stamp = BO.bostamp
WHERE BO.date < @findate AND BO.tabela1 NOT IN ('INSTALED','CANCELED')
ORDER BY bo2.u_registration_date
```

Comment: ...though you could comment that, in certain scenarios, the union version _might_ run faster depending on the index scheme.  But +1 to your answer either way.

Comment: If I don't use `UNION` my query doesn't return me anything between the dates I've selected in the first place, it doesn't show me any data from within the dates I specify

Comment: `UNION` doesn't filter data, @pauLo_0liveira . It just combines 2+ datasets with the same definition and returns the `DISTINCT` rows from the 2+ datasets. If a `UNION` query returns rows, then at least one inner query will too.

Comment: I added `bo2.u_registration_date` to both selects and the alias after the parenthesis, but now my error is that it doesn't find `bo2.u_registration_date`, I've tried adding it after `select *`, but for it to recognize I need to add `BO2` before the parenthesis.

Comment: @Larnu I think I need the `UNION` because I'm combining 2 queries into one, but I might be doing it wrong. The code @GMB suggested, without `UNION` only returns me part of what I need.

Comment: @pauLo_0liveira: please try and run the first query exactly as provided.

Comment: it worked, I was being ordering by `bo2.u_registration_date` rather than just `u_registration_date`. Thank you very much